# Как сделать запрос для подсчета кол-ва всех новых комментариев во всех темах для пользователя с учетом даты последнего просмотра темы пользователем?

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблица с темами

```
topics

id | title
------------
1  | topic_1
------------
2  | topic_2
```

Таблица с комментариями

```
comments

id | topic_id | text      | date_added
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | some_text | 2018-12-10 12:00:00
-----------------------------------------------
2  | 1        | some_text | 2018-12-10 12:10:00
-----------------------------------------------
3  | 2        | some_text | 2018-12-10 13:00:00
```

Таблица с датами просмотра тем пользователями. Одна запись, которая обновляется, если пользователь посмотрел тему. Если еще не просматривал, то записи нет (для пользователя id1 нет записи, так как темы он не просматривал):

```
topics_views

id | user_id | topic_id | date_last_view
---------------------------------------------
1  | 2       |  1       | 2018-12-10 14:00:00
```

Делаю запрос, чтобы получить количество непрочитанных комментариев для пользователя id1 во всех темах:

```
select t.id, 
       t.title, 
       count(c.id) count_comments 
  from topics t
       left join comments c on c.topic_id = t.id
       left join topics_views v on v.topic_id = t.id
  where (v.user_id = 1
    and c.date_added > v.date_last_view) or v.date_last_view is null
  group by t.id, 
           t.title
```

Результат:

```
[0] => array ([id] => 2,
              [title] => topic_2,
              [count_comments ] => 1);
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[0] => array ([id] => 1,
              [title] => topic_1,
              [count_comments ] => 2)
[1] => array ([id] => 2,
              [title] => topic_2,
              [count_comments ] => 1)
```

Как сделать запрос правильно?

Comment: *Таблица с датами просмотра тем пользователями* Одна запись на пару `(юзер, тема)` (т.е. пара уникальна), или запись на каждый просмотр?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `Left join topics_views` вы сейчас подклеиваете записи по всем пользователям. После чего в фразе where пытаетесь получить записи у которых в этой таблице ничего нет (условием `v.date_last_view is null`) (ни одного комментария ни он одного пользователя). Или берете только записи пользователя с id=1, но конкретно для него в данной выборке записей нет, в базе есть только комментарии пользователя id=2. Совершенно закономерно ни одна запись с имеющейся датой date_last_view не берется, потому что она относилась к другому пользователю.

Что бы все работало вам надо изначально left join брать только записи с нужным пользователем, причем только за нужные даты, т.е. перенести все условия из where в сам join:

```
select t.id, 
       t.title,
       count(c.id) count_comments 
  from topics t
       left join comments c on c.topic_id = t.id
       left join topics_views v on v.topic_id = t.id and v.user_id = 1 and c.date_added > v.date_last_view
   group by t.id, t.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала для каждой темы получаем дату последнего просмотра (или NULL), а затем выбираем комментарии после этой даты (или все)

```
select t.id, 
       t.title, 
       count(c.id) count_comments 
  from topics t
       left join topics_views v on v.topic_id = t.id and v.user_id = 1
       left join comments c on c.topic_id = t.id and (c.date_added > v.date_last_view or v.date_last_view is null)
  group by t.id, 
           t.title
```